# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple cousera deeplearnig.ai

Tags: python, deep-learning, logistic-regression

Can anyone help?
I was doing deep learning from deeplearning.ai
I am on my week 2 of course 1
my propagate function is as follow
Forward Propagation:

You get X
You compute  A=σ(wTX+b)=(a(1),a(2),...,a(m−1),a(m))A=σ(wTX+b)=(a(1),a(2),...,a(m−1),a(m)) 
You calculate the cost function:  J=−1m∑mi=1y(i)log(a(i))+(1−y(i))log(1−a(i))J=−1m∑i=1my(i)log⁡(a(i))+(1−y(i))log⁡(1−a(i))

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: propagate

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

    Tips:
    - Write your code step by step for the propagation. np.log(), np.dot()
    """

    m = X.shape[1]

    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A = sigmoid(np.dot((w.T,X)+b))                                    # compute activation
    cost = -1/m*np.sum(Y*np.log(A)+(1-Y)*np.log(1-A), axis=1,keepdims=True)                                 # compute cost
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dw = 1/m*dot((X,(A-Y).T))
    db = 1/m*np.sum(A-Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost
```

and

```
w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1.],[2.]]), 2., np.array([[1.,2.,-1.],[3.,4.,-3.2]]), np.array([[1,0,1]])
grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

however i was getting following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 3 grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)

---> 26     A = sigmoid(np.dot((w.T,X)+b))                                    # compute activation

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

how to resolve?
my sigmoid function is working fine..

Comment: What result do you expect from `(w.T, X) + b`? For example, what is result of `(1, 2) + 3`? Maybe you want to use `np.dot(w.T,X)+b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the expression `np.dot((w.T,X)+b)`. In this expression, you apply function `np.dot` to *one* parameter `(w.T,X)+b`. That, in turn, consists of the tuple `(w.T, X)` and a floating-point number `b` that you try to add together (and that is not possible).

The problem is with your parentheses. You want to call the function with *two* parameters `w.T` and `X` and then add `b` to the result: `np.dot(w.T,X)+b`.